# Meteor collection not displaying

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I am trying to display my Orders collection. The Orders collection schema has a select field populated from the Items collection.

I cannot seem to get the Orders collection to display on my admin's template. I have verified that I am posting to the collection with Mongol and I'm not receiving any errors in console. I have also tried displaying it in a tabular table with no luck.

Any ideas? I'm still learning meteor and have been staring at this screen for hours.. maybe need some fresh air now and a fresh look later...

**/collections/orders.js**

```
Orders = new Mongo.Collection("orders");
    Orders.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
      station: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Station',
        max: 2,
      },
      itemselect: {
        type: [String],
        label: 'Items',
        optional: false,
        autoform:{
          type: "select",
          options : function()  {
            return Items.find().map(function (c) {
              return {label: c.name , value: c._id}
            })
          }
        }
      }
    }));
```

**/templates/admin.html**

```
<template name="ordersTable">
  <div class="admin">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Orders</button>
         </a>
       </h4>
     </div>
     <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
       <div class="panel-body">
         <ul>
           {{#each orders}}
             <li>{{> station}}</li>
           {{/each}}
         </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="panel-footer">
         {{> addOrderFormAdmin}}
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**/templates/admin.js** < This ended up being my problem..

```
Template.dashboard.rendered = function() {
  return Orders.find();
};
```

**should be a helper.. so this instead:

```
Template.ordersTable.helpers({
  orders: function () {
    return Orders.find();
  }
});
```

**Insert Order Form**

```
<template name="addOrderFormAdmin">
  {{> autoformModals}} <!-- this is required for this modal to open -->
    {{#afModal class="btn btn-primary" collection="Orders" operation="insert"}}
      Add New Order
    {{/afModal}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code inside your `dashboard` `rendered` callback does not make any sense. I think you want to create a [**helper function**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers) for your `ordersTable` template instead:

```
Template.ordersTable.helpers({
  orders: function () {
    return Orders.find();
  }
});
```

Furthermore, please note that `Template.myTemplate.rendered` is deprecated in Meteor version 1.0.4.2 (and later), use **[`Template.myTemplate.onRendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered)** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check publish and subscribe if you have removed the autopublish package. First, see if you can reach the collection through the console(on the web page, not the command line). Second, see if the collection is updated after your posts (for this you could use the command line by typing "meteor mongo" while the server is running or just download Robomongo).

Comment: I have autopublish and insecure enabled. I can access the collection through the browser devtool console and see the collection objects when I Orders.find().fetch()

I can also still access the collection through Mongol.

Comment: I can also access the collection objects via db.orders.find() in console.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate helper function to display "orders" at .templates/admin. I mean the ordinary helper like "return Orders.find()"

Comment: No. This is what I was lacking. I had 'return Orders.find() but in my Template.dashboard.rendered instead of in a Template.ordersTable.helpers like Matthias mentions below.